# Nested groupBy of JSON objects using underscore JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, underscore.js

I am trying to group json data as per their category and its count in bracket. The hierarchy is something like

[image: Menu]

I have created one [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/22LSRzEc1BBR9JwNtujz?p=preview) where I have grouped it for "BroadCategory" using `underscore.js` function called `_.groupBy`

In one of my approaches I thought I should group in below seq:

> MainCategory -> GeneralCategory -> BroadCategory

and implemented code like:

```
  var grpArray = _.groupBy(products, function (element) {
    return element.category.MainCategory;
   });

 var grp2 = _.groupBy(grpArray, function (element) {
   for (var count = 0; count < element.length ; count++){
      return (element[count].category.GeneralCategory); // Problem here is that 
    //it returns value at count=0 and so loop ends , so other objects of MainCategory array is skipped
    }
 })
```

but  `grp2` was not in the way I expected it to be.

Comment: This isn't fully optimized and doesn't use underscore but generates html expected results  http://plnkr.co/edit/1GO0ZFljUc74ITOh6BhE?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks u so much. This was an amazing solution. Please put this as an answer so that it can help others as well :)